# Suggested edits still not approved

Tags: support, review, suggested-edits

I've submitted too many edits, which isn't unusual for me, and when I try to edit anymore posts, I get the message saying that I need to wait for my other submitted edits to be approved (as you do).

But here's the thing:

My edits **still** haven't been reviewed and processed, and I haven't been able to edit due to the fact that my currently submitted edits have yet to be reviewed.

When can I expect my submitted edits to be approved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I've submitted too many edits, which isn't unusual for me, and when I try to edit anymore posts, I get the message saying that I need to wait for my other submitted edits to be approved (as you do).

You might want to slow down on the amount of edit proposals you are making.  Manu of your recent edit proposal have been rejected.  Your edit proposals seem focused on questions that have more than just grammatical errors but are also lacking in focus.

For instance this [edit proposal](https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/985488) is to answer that is replying to an existing answer to the question.  The answer itself should be flagged for removal instead of superfluous edits.  While I have only provided a single example, I could provide additional examples of prior edit proposals that are superfluous, but I won’t be doing that in this answer.

> My edits still haven't been reviewed and processed, and it's probably been about two full days I haven't been able to edit because my currently submitted edits have yet to be reviewed.

Your edit proposals were reviewed within 24 hours of being proposed.

> When can I expect my submitted edits to be approved?

This depends on the activity of the community on any given day.  Due to the fact, the edit queue isn’t very large, that typically happens within a few hours (but not always).

Please concentrate on improving the quality of your edit proposals.  Low-quality edit proposals hurt the community.

**In the last 10 days I keep seeing edit proposals that don't attempt to solve all problems with construction.**  Sadly, due to my activity in the review queue, I end up having to review some of these proposals.  **Now, I am trying to give you feedback, but I am forced to reject edit proposals on content that really shouldn't be improved.**

- This [edit](https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/986891) and this [edit](https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/986244) does not resolve all the problems with the contributions.
- This [edit](https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/986705) is attempting to improve a question that will eventually be deleted.  **While you improved the grammar, the actual problem with the contribution was not solved.**
- [Edit](https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/985487) proposals like this just prevent editors from reviewing proposals that help real content.  **An answer that indicates they also have the problem, and they returned the items to Amazon, should be deleted not improved.**

Answer (score 5):

Please have a little patience: [4 out of 5 of your pending suggested edits](https://superuser.com/users/1164599/virtuality?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) are **less than 10 hours old.** You're lucky not to be on Stack Overflow where edits may take a full week (because the queue is so full) or on [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/users/34061/glorfindel?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) (yes, those are edits pending since last November).

I approved some of them but they'll need more reviews. In the meantime, I would like to suggest to please focus on editing posts that really need/deserve it; your edits are generally good, but [polishing turds](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/155961/295232) isn't really useful.