# The edit queue is full at the moment - enlarge number of items?

Tags: feature-request, status-review

I have only recently started editing some posts.

In the last few days I often get the error message attached as a screenshot or similar messages about a full review queue.

The message also appears, for example, if I have waited one night.

Can the size for the number of items within the queue be expanded?

---

[image]

Comment: @Giacomo: Yes - my first thought was that the queue itself should be expanded. But I didn't remember that as a new user I can have at most 5 pending edits. In this case the message is indeed weird. On StackOverflow I also have higher privileges for some time and no problems.

Comment: While I agree that 40 edits *sounds* like a small number I'm not sure what we would want it increased to. 100 feels too large as the queue may look too large to a small number of reviewers. It would be worth seeing how often we hit our review limit. Tagged as status-review for a CM to look at.

Comment: Made its way into our backlog, @Mokubai — once a CM is assigned to look into the issue, we'll get back to you with more updates :)

Comment: Good to know. Thanks @JNat

Comment: @JNat has there been any progress or response to this?

Comment: Not yet, @Mokubai, I'm afraid. As soon as we have updates, you'll have updates, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently it is possible that we only have a suggested edit queue of 40 edits:

[What's the fixed size of the suggested edit queue?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84362/whats-the-fixed-size-of-the-suggested-edit-queue) tells us that we only have 40 edits pending at a time.  While there are currently on 35 edits waiting for review you may have hit it when there were 40 edits pending.

---

An alternative issue...

New editors can have at most 5 pending edits.  Until those edits are approved you will not be able to submit new edits.

All you can do is wait for people to review the edits and approve or reject them.

[Rate limit suggested edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210416/rate-limit-suggested-edits/281202#281202)

Comment: There is [some suggestion that the message was more helpful](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/14140/suggested-edits-still-not-approved) in the recent past, but I do not know if this is indeed a bug or our suggested edit queue is particularly small. At the moment I see 35 edits in review and I'd be surprised if that was our limit. [So] apparently has a limit that [was 200 but is now 500](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345125/suggested-edit-queue-is-full) so we could have a small queue...

Comment: @Mokubai: Checked as answered. My feature request to expand to at least 50 or better 100 entries remains.

Comment: Lots of task queues get fuller at this time of year as people are running around trying to win Hats ;)

Comment: The queue is STILL FULL  - after the Hats event ended. I cannot do quality edits, So the site ends up storing poor quality posts. What is the reason behind such policy?..

Comment: Read the first link in my answer. This is a network wide issue. Also, per the comments under the question raising the limits is under investigation.